# Migrating to VB.NET: what datatype to use for "hcontext" in an x64 project?

Tags: vb.net, vb6, 64-bit, vb6-migration, type-conversion

I have a old VB6 project.Now I migrating it in VB.Net on vs2008 and the solution platform now I have to use 64bit.In the old code the variable `hContext` was declared as Integer.

```
 Dim hContext As Integer
```

And used as:

```
Dim rc As Integer
dwScope = SCARD_SCOPE_USER
rc = SCardEstablishContext(dwScope, 0, 0, hContext)
```

When I debug the code the hContext create problem.
This is due to it define as a Integer(32bit).

Now the problem is "What datatype should I use for hContext"? I have also used different datatype like Long, ULong, IntPtr....

**NOTE**
When I debug the code the hcontext take 4byte address.but in 64bit I take hContext as IntPtr which is platform dependent,But it show only 1byte address. And I am not able to establish the connection.

Comment: I believe that Long is the 64 bit integer type.

Comment: Yes you are right,But its not working.

Comment: The architecture doesn't affect the size of the variables. and integer is 32 bits in x64 and x86 systems (64 bit and 32 bit systems).

Comment: Did you get the incorrect result when use `Long` or `ULong`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suspect the question is "what is the correct signature for [SCardEstablishContext](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/aa379479%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) in a 64-bit project?"

The C WinAPI signature is as follows:

```
LONG WINAPI SCardEstablishContext(
  __in   DWORD dwScope,
  __in   LPCVOID pvReserved1,
  __in   LPCVOID pvReserved2,
  __out  LPSCARDCONTEXT phContext
);
```

Pointer types ("LP...") should be `IntPtr` and LONG/DWORD types should map to `Integer` -- this will be correct for a WinAPI call in either a 32-bit or a 64-bit build. (In some cases it is nice to specify a managed structure type *instead* of `IntPtr` and let the .NET interoperability/pinvoke automatically marshal everything.)

[pinvoke.net](http://www.pinvoke.net/) is sometimes helpful -- see [pinvoke.net: SCardEstablishConnection](http://www.pinvoke.net/default.aspx/winscard.scardestablishcontext) <del>and *note how the VB.NET signature at top is wrong</del> -- but care needs to be taken because definitions are sometimes incorrect and/or incomplete ;-)

The correct pinvoke signature, for an opaque context value, is:

```
<DllImport("winscard.dll", SetLastError:=True)>
Public Shared Function SCardEstablishContext(
    dwScope as Integer,
    pvReserved1 as IntPtr,
    pvReserved2 as IntPtr,
    <out>() phContext as IntPtr) As Integer
End Function
```

Happy coding.

Comment: @vikky Make sure the signature matches above -- not all are Integer, not all are IntPtr; it depends on how they are defined in the C WinAPI. If there is still a specific runtime error, post the specific exception in the original post.

Answer (score 0):

An integer in VB.Net is defined as 32bits, even when running in a 64bit process.

From the [MSDN docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/06bkb8w2.aspx):

> Holds signed 32-bit (4-byte) integers that range in value from -2,147,483,648 through 2,147,483,647.

Your `SCardEstablishContext()` function likely calls to unmanaged code that wants to be 32bit.  Therefore I would use Integer.

You may also have to specify an x86 (32bit) soluction (rather than Any CPU or x64/64bit) because of this function reference.